# Remove duplicates from paired rows before counting values

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas, matplotlib

I have a Python program I am trying to convert from CSV to SQLite, I have managed to do everything apart from remove duplicates for counting entries. My database is JOINed. I'm reading the database like this:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT d.id AS is, mac.add AS mac etc etc
```

I have tried `df.drop_duplicates('tablename1','tablename2')`

and

```
 df.drop_duplicates('row[1],row[3]')
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

The below code is what I used with the CSV version & I would like to replicate for the Python SQLite script.

```
for row in reader:
    key = (row[1], row[2])

    if key not in entries:
        writer.writerow(row)
        entries.add(key)

del writer
```

Comment: Why don't you just `select distinct` in your sql query and have it filter via the database instead of doing it in Python?: http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-select-distinct

Comment: The DISTINCT clause allows you to remove the duplicate rows in the result however, I am unsure how DISTINCT row1 & row 3 together as part of the query.

Comment: If it's anything like Sybase, it will work

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT devices.id AS id...` it works with multiple columns

Answer (score 1):

have you tried running `SELECT DISTINCT col1,col2 FROM table` first?

In your case it might be as simple as placing the `DISTINCT` keyword prior to your column names.

Comment: Exactly my thought (from my comment in the OP) :). You may wish to add a link which explains how to use distinct: http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-select-distinct

Comment: Many of the columns have multiple enteries. The only entiers i with to remove were those that would have the same value in row1 and row3 not just row1 or just row3. Thank you for your reply, I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `subset` parameter

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['tablename1','tablename2'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you piRSquared, The missing subset is all i needed, thank you.

You need to use the subset parameter
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['tablename1','tablename2'])

Will also look into SELECT DISTINCT but for now, subset works.

Comment: If my post answered your question, don't forget to upvote and mark it as the answer

Comment: Thank you, will do.